# Necesito añadir '\' utilizando el comando join

Tags: python, json, xml, lista, join

Esto es la parte de mi codigo donde quiero realizar un join separando los elementos de mi lista con el caracter '\' pero al reconocermelo como un comentario, no se si existe alguna forma especial de ponerlo al ser un caracter especial, porque por mas que pruebo solo consigo que me aparezcan dos barras en vez de una o algun otro carracter que le meto para cerrar el comentario.

```
            lista_final = '\\'.join(lista_final)
            archivo_smil.append(lista_final + '\n')
    print(archivo_smil)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supongo que `archivo_smil` es una lista de cadenas. Completemos tu código con datos de prueba para que pueda mostrar lo que pretendo:

```
archivo_smil = ["Primera cadena", "Segunda cadena"]
lista_final = ["carpeta1", "carpeta2", "carpeta3"]

# Y ahora tu código
lista_final = '\\'.join(lista_final)
archivo_smil.append(lista_final + '\n')
print(archivo_smil)
```

Esto muestra en la salida:

```
['Primera cadena', 'Segunda cadena', 'carpeta1\\carpeta2\\carpeta3\n']
```

pero a pesar de las apariencias, es correcto. El carácter `\` no aparece repetido dentro de la cadena. Es sólo que python lo muestra así debido a que lo que estás imprimiendo es una lista, y por tanto python te da la *representación* de la lista (con corchetes alrededor y elementos separados por comas). Y ya que los elementos de la lista son cadenas, te da a su vez la *representación* de esas cadenas (entre comillas y con los caracteres especiales dentro tal como los escribirías tú en un programa python). Fíjate de hecho que hasta el `\n` aparece.

Pero eso es sólo la forma de mostrarlo, no lo que contiene. No contiene `\\` sino un solo `\`, así como no contiene `\n` como la secuencia de caracteres `\` y `n`, sino como un solo carácter "nueva línea".

La demostración de que es así la obtienes si iteras sobre esa lista e imprimes cada elemento. En este caso python ya no te mostraría su *representación*, sino su *decodificación*, haciendo que `\n` produzca una nueva línea, que cada `\` se muestre "tal cual", y decodificando caracteres unicode si los hubiera para que puedan ser entendidos por el *encoding* de la terminal.

Así:

```
for elemento in archivo_smil:
  print(elemento)
```

```
Primera cadena
Segunda cadena
carpeta1\carpeta2\carpeta3
```

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración!

Answer (score 0):

Podrías intentar primero juntar con un caracter que no te genere problemas y luego sustituirlo:

```
lista=["A","B","C","D"]
join="J".join(lista)
join=join.replace("J","\\")
print(join)
```

También depende de lo que tengas en `lista_final`. Si son números, quizás el problema se resuelva volviéndolos un string.